# docker-compose 'command' usage

Tags: docker, docker-compose, kibana

I've been trying to follow this:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

My aim is to execute a bash script after an image has been started.
This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.9.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
  logstash:
    image: logstash:7.9.1
    container_name: logstash
    ports:
      - 4560:4560
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/logstash.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
  kibana:
    build: ./kibana
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://elasticsearch:9200
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    command: ["./scripts/script.sh"]
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM kibana:7.9.1
COPY script.sh /scripts/script.sh
```

I keep getting the following error:
[dumb-init] /scripts/script.sh : No such file or directory.

Comment: The Compose `command:` replaces the Dockerfile `CMD`, and runs _instead of_ the main container process that was declared in the image.

Comment: What implications does that have? does it mean the Dockerfile is not being used to build the image?

Comment: can you see your kibana image when running 'docker images' command

Comment: I found a typo: missing a . at the start of the COPY command

Comment: @DavidMaze Maze can you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? you were right all along

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I have finished this task. My approach was wrong from the beginning, using command inside docker-compose.yml DOES NOT add the script to the initialization of the kibana image, it just REPLACES it. You need to modify the init script the guys from kibana use. These are the steps:

Make sure that the kibana image is being created from a dockerfile:

```
kibana:
    build: ./kibana
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://elasticsearch:9200
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

Then in the dockerfile pass the canvas to the container's filessystem along with a modified version of the init script:

```
FROM kibana:7.9.1
COPY kibana-docker /usr/local/bin/kibana-docker
COPY canvas.ndjson   /usr/local/bin/canvas.ndjson
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/kibana-docker"]
```

And finally include my logic inside the init script(kibana docker) but before the exec instruction:

```
response="500"
while [ $response != "200" ]
do

sleep 20
response=$(curl -so /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n" localhost:5601/status) 
if [ $response = "200" ]
then
curl -X POST localhost:5601/api/saved_objects/_import -H "kbn-xsrf: true" --form file=@/usr/local/bin/canvas.ndjson
fi

done &
exec /usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana --cpu.cgroup.path.override=/ --cpuacct.cgroup.path.override=/ ${longopts} "$@"
```